# getElementsByTagName not detecting SVG -- PHP

Tags: php, html, svg, domdocument

I'm trying to take `<svg>` content from HTML and put it into an array for later use.  My code...

```
$html_content = '
<div class="stage" id="shape_1"><svg height="100" version="1.1" width="350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.316681px; top: -0.650024px;"><desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc><defs/><rect x="75" y="25" width="200" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#90ee90" stroke="#000" style="fill-opacity: 0.5;" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0"/><path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M75,25L275,25" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/><path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M275,25L275,75" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/><path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M275,75L75,75" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/><path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M75,75L75,25" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/><text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 15px Arial;" x="175" y="85" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,6.5)" font-family="Arial" font-size="15px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal"><tspan dy="5">x + 10 ft.</tspan></text><text style="text-anchor: end; font: 15px Arial;" x="65" y="50" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="15px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal"><tspan dy="5">x ft.</tspan></text></svg></div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_content);

$svg = $doc->getElementsByTagName('svg');
foreach ($svg as $svg_item) {
    array_push($svg_array, $svg_item);
}

print_r($svg_array);
```

The problem is that `$svg_array` is empty.  I know there is definitely `<svg>` content in `$html_content` though.

BTW, I'm getting several warnings on the page overall (as I'm running the above code in a loop).  They're like...

"Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 46 in..."

or

"Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag c invalid in Entity, line: 119 in..."

---

**Edit:** Upon deeper investigation, a stripped down version of my code produces the following warnings...

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag svg invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag desc invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag defs invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag rect invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag text invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag tspan invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag text invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag tspan invalid in Entity, line: 2 in.....

Perhaps `<svg>` isn't supported????

---

**Thoughts?**

Comment: Yep, you should at a minimum, be adding the actual code to the question (or a cut-down copy that exhibits the same problem) . It sure sounds an awful lot like the html is malformed. While you know the $htmlContent to contain something, how do you know it's even loaded properly and makes it through to the $doc object?

Comment: @enhzflep: I'm outputting it and the proper content shows up in the proper way.

Comment: You've been here for long enough to know than an MCVE is always recommended. If you choose not to provide one, don't be surprised if readers choose not to answer your question. :shrugs: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have code in my post.  The full content of `$html_content` is too long to post. :shrugs:

Comment: create a [mcve] then by cutting down the html to something minimal.

Comment: My original post has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question may be more easily teased apart now that the offending html string is included, and may be further investigated by spreading the input text over multiple lines. When done so, we get an input string spread over 17 lines. We can then use the warning messages and the line numbers to quickly identify the parts of the input that are hurting the parser.

```
'<div class="stage" id="shape_1">
    <svg height="100" version="1.1" width="350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.316681px; top: -0.650024px;">
    <desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc>
    <defs/>
    <rect x="75" y="25" width="200" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#90ee90" stroke="#000" style="fill-opacity: 0.5;" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0"/>
    <path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M75,25L275,25" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
    <path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M275,25L275,75" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
    <path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M275,75L75,75" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
    <path style="stroke-opacity: 0.8;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M75,75L75,25" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
    <text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 15px Arial;" x="175" y="85" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,6.5)" font-family="Arial" font-size="15px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal">
        <tspan dy="5">x + 10 ft.</tspan>
    </text>
    <text style="text-anchor: end; font: 15px Arial;" x="65" y="50" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="15px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal">
    <tspan dy="5">x ft.</tspan>
    </text>
    </svg>
</div>';
```

Now if we stop and think about it for a second, SVG actually isn't html - it's a dialect of XML too. Same parent, but still not one and the same, we're embedding XML inside HTML for lack of better terminology, when we use an SVG in the manner that you have. With that in mind, it hardly seems surprising at all that the 17 input lines result in the following warning messages. The entities mentioned are indeed not standard HTML ones. (tag is 5th word of each line - svg, desc, defs, etc, etc)

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag svg invalid in Entity, line: 2 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag desc invalid in Entity, line: 3 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag defs invalid in Entity, line: 4 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag rect invalid in Entity, line: 5 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 6 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 7 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 8 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 9 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag text invalid in Entity, line: 10 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag tspan invalid in Entity, line: 11 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag text invalid in Entity, line: 13 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag tspan invalid in Entity, line: 14 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\*redacted*\svg.php on line 23
```

So, what to do? Simple. Rather than trying to load XML with the loadHTML method, simply use the loadXML method instead. Once done, the output becomes this:

```
Array ( [0] => DOMElement Object ( [tagName] => svg [schemaTypeInfo] => [nodeName] => svg [nodeValue] => Created with Raphaël 2.1.2 x + 10 ft. x ft. [nodeType] => 1 [parentNode] => (object value omitted) [childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) [previousSibling] => (object value omitted) [nextSibling] => (object value omitted) [attributes] => (object value omitted) [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted) [namespaceURI] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg [prefix] => [localName] => svg [baseURI] => file:/C:/xampp2/htdocs/*redacted*/ [textContent] => Created with Raphaël 2.1.2 x + 10 ft. x ft. ) )
```

Comment: html [includes SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg) so it really **is** html these days

Answer (score 0):

Hmm could this be that PHP does not support this?

The following example gets the svg through javascripts getElementsByTagName:

```js
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
console.log(e[0]);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't well with HTML5 elements such as SVG.  Most of the advice on the Web is to turn off errors in order to have it work with HTML5.

Comment: Indeed. While HTML5 allows one to define their own elements/entities, the loadHTML method is somewhat unhelpful when one has defined their own tags. In the case of embedded SVG, it's not actually HTML, rather it's XML and as such, contains tags not recognized by the HTML parser - a situation no different than that encountered when trying to parse HTML5 code containing custom elements. Downvote countered.